# The User does not exist or is not unique - Content Deployment (MOSS 2007)

Tags: 2007, content-deployment

I am having a Incremental Content Deployment scheduled from Stage to Production. Now it is throwing an error The User does not exist or is not unique . I have checked the logs as well as eventviewer. It says only the above error message . How do i find which user is creating the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the *Manifest.xml* file contains all deployed objects which may help you determining which of the objects (including users) might broke. Manifest file is only completed at the end of the Export phase.

See more details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maximeb/archive/2008/05/16/sharepoint-content-deployment-manifest-reader.aspx)

Comment: I have tried this already

Comment: how does the Content Deployment set up look like?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. One of our team member deleted the Users from the Production Site and i was not able to add the users from stage because the account was disabled in AD. Now we have enabled the account and added the user back in stage . Now the Content Deployment ran successful